# Lotka Volterra equations - Proving solutions are positive without solving the system.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have a system describing two species:

$$y'_1=a_1y_1\left(1-\frac{y_1}{N_1}\right)-b_1y_1y_2 \\ y'_2=a_2y_2\left(1-\frac{y_2}{N_2}\right)-b_2y_2y_1$$

where $a_i,N_i,b_i>0.$

Carrying out stability analysis is straightforward. But I want to show that the solutionvector $[y_1(t) \ \ \ y_2(t)]$ is always positive if I start with $y_1(0),y_2(0)>0$.

Also, how can I prove that $[y_1(t) \ \ \ y_2(t)]<\infty?$

Comment: Are you sure about your system? Both "species" decrease after interaction? One of the minus signs after the logistic term should probably be a plus sign.

Comment: This is a competitive system, so I don't think it needs to be a positive sign. Look here https://www.kristakingmath.com/blog/predator-prey-systems.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking of it as a Predator-prey system... Regarding the positivity, I think that solution uniqueness may do the trick. There are solutions "living" in the axis ($y_1=0$ with $y_2$ following a logistic equation and vice versa) so, if you can use uniqueness, a solution starting in the first quadrant that crosses the axis would have to coincide with a solution that never leaves the axis.

Comment: Are you referring to the Picard-Lagerlöf theorem? I don't understand your last sentence. Why would it have to coincide with a solution that never leaves the axis?

Comment: And if a solution crosses an axis, its not in the first quadrant so I don't understand.

Comment: I am reasoning by contradiction. Imagine that a solution starts in the first quadrant and at some point reaches the axis. At that point it will cross another solution (one of the form $(y_1,0)$ or $(0,y_2)$, that always exists and can even by explicitly computed). Uniqueness of solution implies those two solution are actually the same, meaning that you must have started on the axis and contradicts the fact that you were starting in the interior of the first quadrant.

Comment: What do you mean by $[y_1(t)\ \ y_2(t)]<\infty$?

Comment: @Parseval Yes I was thinking of Picard's theorem, but sime extra work is needed in order to show that the solution are global in time.

Comment: @PierreCarre - Ok, I'll make an attempt to show this in a edit then maybe you can see if I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: @user539887 - I mean that the solutions can never go off to infinity.

Comment: A hint: compare the $i$-th coordinate, $i = 1, 2$, of a solution of the system with a solution of $y'_i=a_iy_i(1-\frac{y_i}{N_i})$.

Comment: What is "the $i$-th coordinate?" You mean like $(y_1,y_2)$? And in your last part, why have you only chosen $y_1$ and $N_1$?

Comment: The first coordinate of $[y_1\ \ y_2]$ is $y_1$, the second coordinate is $y_2$. I say: compare a function satisfying $y'_1=a_1y_1(1-\frac{y_1}{N_1})-b_1y_1y_2$ with (an appropriately chosen) function satisfying $y'_1=a_1y_1(1-\frac{y_1}{N_1})$ (and similarly for the second coordinate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we search solutions of the form $(y_1, 0)$ or $(0,y_2)$ we see that they are of the form $(y_1^*,0)$ or $(0,y_2^*)$, where $y_i^*$ is a solution of the logistic equation $y_i'=a_i y_i (1- \frac{y_i}{N_i})$. In phase space these solutions are straight lines on the axis, starting at some point in the axis and approaching $(0,0)$, $(0,N_2)$ or $(N_1,0)$. Assuming that the system has one an only one solution for each given initial condition $y_1(0)=u_0>0$, $y_2(0)=v_0>0$, defined for all $t>0$ (this needs to be proven), we can show by contradiction that $(y_1(t),y_2(t))$ will remain in the interior of the first quadrant.

In  fact, if we admit that a solution starting in the interior of the first quadrant  reaches the axis, the uniqueness of solution tells us that this solution must coincide with a solution of the form $(y_1^* ,0)$ or $(0,y_2^*)$, which is obviously a contradiction. Therefore the solution will not reach the axis and both components will remain positive.